# How to show/Hide UINavigationBar based on UITableview scroll up and down?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uiscrollviewdelegate

I just want to **show UINavigationBar initial** and I just want to **hide the bar when the user starts to scroll down** to view the other items. Once the user **started to scroll up I want to show the navigation bar again with animation**. (Ex: Instagram iOS application. They are hiding the navigation bar when the user starts to scroll down and they are showing the bar when we starts to scroll up.)

I tried to track the tableview scrolling used the **UIScollViewDelegates** but, am not able to achieve it.
Can anyone please suggest me? Looking forward your help. Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve this using storyboard by clicking on the navigation controllers navigation bar and in the attributes tab select 'Hide Bars' and then your appropriate option. Either on swipe, on tap, when keyboard appears. On swipe in your case

Comment: I used scrollViewDidScroll delegate method as it responds to UITableViewDelegate also. Here is the code you might want to look at https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2c0zw6yvchaia5/FailedBanks.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Try AMScrollingNavBar as it works with everything(Scroll View, Table View, Collection View, Web View) .

https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar